# Alternative of ul in python

Tags: python, math, integer, long-integer

In C++ I can use `ul` or `1ul` which represents an `unsigned long int` with a value of `1` represented at the bit level as: `00000000000000000000000000000001`. Similarly we can use `2ul` and so on.

My question is what is the alternative of `ul` in python.

Comment: Python has infinitely large (well, theoretically) signed integers. What do you want to do with the integer?

Comment: Did you mean to ask: `My question is what is the equivalent of ul in python`?

Comment: @MichaelButscher i have a program in c++ from github which i need to convert in python, for that purpose i need this. This is the c++ code
 long double a = sqrt(1ul+4*(x))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're relying on the *limitations* of `unsigned long` (e.g. rollover from `ULONG_MAX` to `0` on increment and vice-versa on decrement; inability to store negative values), you don't need to worry. Python's `int` type is "infinite precision" (it has limits, because real world computers can't do infinite, but the limits are high enough that you will never encounter them unless you try to do stuff like RSA crypto math without using three-arg `pow`, and even then, it's typically just slow, it still works). So for your use case:

```
a = math.sqrt(1 + (4 * x))  # Or (1 + (4 * x)) ** 0.5
```

works just fine.

If you need to rely on the *limitations* of `unsigned long`, it's uglier; you can use explicit masking with `0xFFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF` after every operation that might overflow, or using the `ctypes.c_ulong` type for all your math (with constant casts back to `c_ulong`), but that's not typically needed, and not needed for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Just write it in python. Numbers like `1ul` in C++ are just an artifact of C++.

```py
import math
x = 14
a = math.sqrt(1 + (4 * x))

print(a)
```

Output:

```
7.54983443527075
```